# Does Apache AGE support Indexing on Nodes/Relationships?

Tags: apache-age

Is it possible to create an index on the nodes/relationships of a graph in AGE? If so, what is the syntax?

I was unable to find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: Hello! Do you mean the index you create with SQL query - like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX node_index ON ...` or you want some way to access the nodes later through the source code? Or is it something else?

Comment: Yes exactly, indexes like that but on node and relationship labels/properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue currently open related to this:

https://github.com/apache/age/issues/45

At this moment seems there no complete support for this. There is an Open PR for OpenCypher as well:
https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/pull/166

If however you are okay with Neo4j you can look into it.
For more information regarding implementation in Cypher queries: https://github.com/Mats-SX/openCypher/blob/c542f94f07fb934254748f4f2ce44612d45866a3/cip/vendor-extensions/neo4j/CIP2016-12-14-Neo4j-indexes.adoc